# Rails - how to add own label in a simple_form_for form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, simple-form

I am using `simple_form_for` for generating forms.

This is a standard way how is rendered an input:

```
    <%= f.input :password, input_html: { class: 'textinput' }, :required => true, :autofocus => true, :placeholder => 'this is heavy' %>
```

On the official Github page of `simple_form` is shown this way to do it:

```
    <%= f.input :password, label: 'Password (at least 8 characters)', input_html: { class: 'textinput' }, :required => true, :autofocus => true, :placeholder => 'this is heavy' %>
```

But when I set it up this way, the label still says **Password**, not **Password (at least 8 characters)**.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use double quotes instead of single quote in your labels.

```
<%= f.input :password, label: "Password (at least 8 characters)", input_html: { class: 'textinput' }, required: true, autofocus: true, placeholder: "this is heavy" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your label should be separate from your input.

```
    <%= f.label :password, "Password (at least 8 characters)" %>
    <%= f.input :password, input_html: { class: 'textinput' }, :required => true, :autofocus => true, :placeholder => 'this is heavy' %>
```

This is also shown on the [Simple Form Git Repo](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form):

Simple Form also allows you to use label, hint, input_field, error and full_error helpers (please take a look at the rdocs for each method for more info):

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :username %>
  <%= f.input_field :username %>
  <%= f.hint 'No special characters, please!' %>
  <%= f.error :username, id: 'user_name_error' %>
  <%= f.full_error :token %>
  <%= f.submit 'Save' %>
<% end %>
```